# UserContext being displayed undefined in

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to pass data from parent to child using context API.

The parent's code:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(null)

return(...

<UserContext.Provider value = "Hello">
                        <Modal ref = {modalRef} close =  {closeModal} display = {display_modal}>
                            TEXT
                        </Modal>
                        </UserContext.Provider>

...)
```

The code of child:

```
const Modal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
    const msg = useContext(UserContext)
```

The error message is displayed in the browser:

*UserContext is not defined no-undef in the child* [at the line mentioned]. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you actually `export` UserContext and `import` it in the child's source file? The error suggests that a variable named `UserContext` doesn't exist wherever that second bit of code is.

Comment: @JLRishe I followed exactly what is given in official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Ok, but you didn't answer my question. In line 1 of the first snippet, you are creating a variable called `UserContext`. Does the code in the second snippet have access to that value somehow (either due to being in the same file as the first snippet or exporting/importing it)? If not, then that code isn't going to work. That's not a React issue; it's a JavaScript fundamentals issue. In the document you linked to, all the components are defined one after the other, as though they are in the same file. If your components are in separate files, then you need to export/import `UserContext`.

Comment: @JLRishe Ooh. Considering that the child is in separate file, can u tell what code to write to exort/import. I am not getting this stuff exactly. [I thought it was occuring automatically due to provider consumer thing].

Answer (score 1):

The UserContext value has to be accessible to the code of the child component. I suggest putting it in a separate file from both components.

UserContext.js

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(null)

export UserContext;
```

Parent.jsx

```
import UserContext from './UserContext';
import Modal from './Modal';

const Parent = ({ }) => {
    return(...

<UserContext.Provider value = "Hello">
                        <Modal ref = {modalRef} close =  {closeModal} display = {display_modal}>
                            TEXT
                        </Modal>
                        </UserContext.Provider>

...);
};
```

Modal.jsx

```
import UserContext from './UserContext';

const Modal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
    const msg = useContext(UserContext);

};

export Modal;
```

You can think of `UserContext` as a "claim ticket" that the child uses to retrieve the value supplied by the parent. Both the parent and child need to be using that same claim ticket in order to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

A separate context.jsx

```
import {createContext} from 'react'

export const UserContext = createContext(null)
```

Parent component:

```
import {UserContext} from './context'

<UserContext.Provider value = {{display_box: [display, setDisplay]}}>
                        <Modal close = {closeHandler}>
                            TEXT
                        </Modal>
  </UserContext.Provider>
```

Child component:

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {UserContext} from './context'

let msg = useContext(UserContext);

    const [display, setDisplay] = msg.display_box
```